# Wrong simulated univ3 swaps using Alchemy alchemy_simulateExecution API

Tags: uniswapv3, alchemy

we are using your API endpoint alchemy_simulateExecution , but for some reason we seem to receive wrong values here.

for example check this tx: 0xc5f4a2a7e8476a9b8477279d659c61f8617f846a8491f26f17262a889634a5bb
this is what we got back from your endpoint (before the tx executed):
"eventLog": {

```
  "decoded": {

    "authority": "ETHERSCAN",

    "eventName": "Swap",

    "inputs": [

      {

        "name": "sender",

        "value": "0xef1c6e67703c7bd7107eed8303fbe6ec2554bf6b",

        "type": "address",

        "indexed": true

      },

      {

        "name": "recipient",

        "value": "0x2c9f0e38720c613c92db3694879737efb1a9ad37",

        "type": "address",

        "indexed": true

      },

      {

        "name": "amount0",

        "value": "42700000000000000",

        "type": "int256",

        "indexed": false

      },

      {

        "name": "amount1",

        "value": "-447622612788253266739",

        "type": "int256",

        "indexed": false

      },

      {

        "name": "sqrtPriceX96",

        "value": "8124031006914156419379421814048",

        "type": "uint160",

        "indexed": false

      },

      {

        "name": "liquidity",

        "value": "378605158609305909765489",

        "type": "uint128",

        "indexed": false

      },

      {

        "name": "tick",

        "value": "92609",

        "type": "int24",

        "indexed": false

      }

    ]

  },

  "address": "0x58fcd403610e772d68726b55183eb958a7581731",

  "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000097b36c7be8c000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe7bbfd05467bf06ccd00000000000000000000000000000000000000668a28f1d7cbe2744084349d2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000502c3a0ddb101866a57100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000169c1",

  "topics": [

    "0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67",

    "0xef1c6e67703c7bd7107eed8303fbe6ec2554bf6b",

    "0x2c9f0e38720c613c92db3694879737efb1a9ad37"

  ]

}
```

then when you check the tx on etherscan after it mined in:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc5f4a2a7e8476a9b8477279d659c61f8617f846a8491f26f17262a889634a5bb#eventlog
the last log of the tx

```
amount0 :
42700000000000000
amount1 :
-447632935184427947142
sqrtPriceX96 :
8124124677896457122913107886196
liquidity :
378605158609305909765489
tick :
92609
```

amount0 is the tokenAmountIn and amount is the (negative) tokenAmountOut.
the tokenAmountIn is the same but the tokenAmountOut is just wrong..
and therefore the sqrtPrice (and in some rare cases even liquidity) is wrong.
so ofc our calculations are wrong as well because they are based on wrong values.

it is this pool: 0x58fcd403610e772d68726b55183eb958a7581731
there was no tx in at least 15 mins before and after that tx on that pool.

also it can not be that the tx got simulated a second time. simply because the sender does not have enough funds to execute the tx again.

So there is nothing else happening to the pool that that one tx and it gets simulated different than it got executed on chain.

We do not see this behavior for uniswapV2 swaps but very frequently (or always) for uniswapV3. We are pretty sure last month it was still working well for uniswapV3. So that is very weird.

Thank you very much for your help here in advance.

https://composer.alchemy.com?share=eJytWUlP40gU.i8_c3DseOOWpMnQUg8gYPoyGqFy_TmxsF1RudLAtPjvU3ZCqOWVCWR8QOJ9Sy3vuRbnt0fXpGq9cw.E2jvzWhBPjD965.6Z18gQK65IAxImNV1D8.LQVc22JgIunoFuRcVaKdoRrzf9v513.vdv7xept6pqBWLWdSDuOWm7EngnVTXJoR7lvJ6hTvfsEdpZXbMn0lLAnQzOmNOc1D3H0SWdMubzJwhSEEFGfA4Ul08.dEL7ebwFCtVGuHqFEDHPt2wNE7tYk3aFjhOljfmp2XeZvXNUJ8qazVbALeGVeFHUelxVFJBvVw_CEwrzmtHH_csl6fpafZM6COMeV9smBz7qsqc4fBakrnH5gDhUSuJwsUpQPeQr9kAoZdtWqwktbPLzfhzWQE3EVFF9YIeQxesXju_FSd1HLTar2px06uuqhU0_dKJqZBX9QczhqoipKgEuq04wrpaWAZiaFelueKUtJFrY4oPYrwem4h3ANGjtIqBbi6bSgl16ZEVBYZdeqcxFX2_jY3GQj.ceHauTjvgvWIEkaogi7GVVC_D2SonCTv0PtnKKBwxR4hoX_4YzVtr0XRjh3zIm8HQdEER1J18YsoKZsGXvEKJT8jN.GTLWtzBri_9tAc_22Qf8o1rYVcBn2jAUH7WCT59NGfcZ6nXUZscYd9m.rKM_b5yjnLr9nBzjeOAizn_1tIajcu5kfuD6UZ5HuC7n.Rpy6IrD1KId4_dax1xE03MtG_JytzMcDmGT35BnuW2x.hS1BLgBbm_gKMXyqdqqXZnKXdDktvA0DGG3wBkaA0S0LplbcQNtITuilKbLw8k0XTcW0Zw2jGG5cCYYZfVPeX3Rj3gYaqo72cItecLPiA4C5jFuMKquVpakD1m8l5ba5fEWNdlbWTWdkGdINEsmqqqHnbrtD8YCuV5hqEPdLRm.fmq1xlHY0C9rxrh5PNTjhuJqeY93VQVszR2ptQOHGrXZNhNlyVEtWF2DWQoobOiH6RhzwAguj_H265DvMEN5tyHNITm6UIdUXdVdsroAfl2ifUZhXa96a0oNUDXyg8lDLW8WYCyXetxUbECeIo2TgB43Fb_sFUWNqmwOskV5SULGYUG6bsP4MLua4hBUuR0QTtcjr6aDoHlsm0be9v8FWYozIXiVy.u.mmsHQfUYrsy726wiVKM227jfKkGbW5oLlha2_bI8LXIfs5nctc6jMKKHTU12JwfHnjXOczmOdspi2C7yr1OvYqryCfLwgdYVtMLeOBHQ0nZrEpqSIfb6z5m3IZw0P3v67ttkyVkjSf5zsMiW.kWYJoFP40m4yIJv8zDOpmmSJWECy3xCstm3MJHOgg2Ki3JC44s4SfyQJvNvycRPAIo09MNlDvHFIoii6XwZz6XirX.TIPG1R2LDq9D7hVEWRvGU6ozPPvFpcp98veVpWCSkNEb46Sfw8xMdTm3.pGd6YvNfn...p.2vjD9L8jCmSQ7picXr_5NTDb7icEr.J8mERnEapyUp4iwP.Ojz7avPqfk.9Qly6geEkFCOJQhLSAvZJYjotAwSIEXmp3K1i2JK_zrJ8xRSEuZlksWURGQSBmkINM7lnOTxNMqzSZHQEsqoOL4H.W9I2KX03DukdkdRoWk0DWXjmVy.JSg.18pY0NdCIDcIb5L4cRKnkSf3ipJx_cFYwssfs3u5J7z_B7SmxyM-